# Vagrant & Virtual Box Error :Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not ready for guest communication-

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

any idea of how to solve the error:

Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.

After do vagrant up?

Comment: Perhaps report a bug to HashiCorp?

Comment: after you installed the operating system on the VM did you install guest integration?

Comment: I just tried installing the VBox extensions, uninstalling and installing VBox and Vagrant.

Those are the currently vagrant modules:

- vagrant-bindfs (0.4.6)
- vagrant-dns (1.0.0)
- vagrant-hostsupdater (1.0.2)
- vagrant-rekey-ssh (0.1.9)
- vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
- vagrant-vbguest (0.11.0)

Vagrant version:  1.8.1 and VBox: 5.0.14

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install VM on Windows make sure you enable "**Virtualization Technology**"  in your PC's BIOS.

[image: Windows BIOS]

Answer (score 0):

Updating to vagrant v `1.8.4` solves this problem.

More discussion on this problem can be found in this closed issue of chef:
https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/5017